# Is RISUG a simple, effective birth control for men?

Tags: medical-science, contraception

I noticed [an article about birth control method for men](http://techcitement.com/culture/the-best-birth-control-in-the-world-is-for-men/) (called [RISUG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_inhibition_of_sperm_under_guidance)) being developed in India. It's described as being *something like* this description of a near perfect contraceptive:

> no babies, no latex, no daily pill to remember, no hormones to interfere with mood or sex drive, no negative health effects whatsoever, and 100 percent effectiveness

The method requires a visit to doctor, who under local anesthetic injects some polymer gel into [vas deferens tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vas_deferens) by what's described as a simple medical procedure (no hospital time - just anesthetic, cut, injection and a band-aid).

The polymer gel, formed by styrene maleic anhydride and dimethyl sulfoxide, coats the inside wall of the vas deferens tube, and "tears apart" any sperm passing through, due to the polymer's pattern of negative/positive polarization ([the polyelectrolytic effect](http://etd.lib.fsu.edu/theses/available/etd-03252004-143258/unrestricted/02-hhr-Chapter1.pdf)).

The procedure is described as cheap, as is the polymer gel. The effect lasts for 10+ years, and can be cancelled by a similar simple doctor procedure.

However, the article does mention some big pharma stuff, and how this all is being hidden if not deliberately, at least because of no monetary incentive involved. Which makes me feel very, very skeptical...

**So, is this RISUG method real?** Is it accurately described in the article, or are the positive sides overblown and negative sides downplayed? Is it wishful thinking, or just a plain hoax?

Further references:

- [Male Contraception Information Project: RISUG](http://www.newmalecontraception.org/risug.htm)
- [Male Contraceptives: RISUG](http://malecontraceptives.org/methods/risug.php)
- [Wired:The Revolutionary New Birth Control Method for Men](http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/04/ff_vasectomy/all/1) *(April 26, 2011)*
- [Digital Journal: RISUG reversible male contraceptive almost ready for U.S. tests](http://digitaljournal.com/article/307482) *(June 3, 2011)*
- [Gizmag: Reversible male contraception method lasts 10 years](http://www.gizmag.com/risug-male-contraception/18824/) *(June 7, 2011)*

*... and [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=risug)...*

Comment: It seems a bit convoluted to me when you know that a vasectomy will achieve the same effect.

Comment: 100 percent effectiveness? I doubt that, as [no current method is 100 percent effective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_birth_control_methods#Effectiveness_of_various_methods), except of course abstinence. I'm also doubting "no negative health effects whatsoever" as all medical procedures carry *some* risk. Sounds to me like a male version of the IUD.

Comment: @Raskolnikov but a vasectomy is considered permanent, while this looks like it is designed to be reversible.

Comment: Considered yes, but they are [in principle reversible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasectomy#Vasectomy_reversal) even though not always completely successfuly. It may just be a question of improving technique. Compare that to a new technique of which the reliability is unknown.

Comment: @Raskolnikov while vasectomies can be and have been reversed, they are still considered permanent birth control. This is a [long acting reversible contraceptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-acting_reversible_contraceptive) which is a completely different beast from permanent birth control. Are you really suggesting **more** choice in contraceptive methods is a bad thing? Is it convoluted that the shot or patch or ring or implant exists because pills have the same effect?

Comment: @SamIAm To be exact, it was described as _something like_ "the perfect contraceptive" (which would have 100% effectivness). One of the other sources said "over 99%" actual effectiveness, I think. Though it should be noted it's not claimed to be very thoroughly tested, so maybe they just haven't enountered the failure conditions yet.

Comment: Although the method is billed as reversible, I see absolutely no credible evidence that it is. They claim that a second injection will reverse it but all the studies they cite are about its efficacy as a contraceptive.

Comment: @NYCProchoiceMD [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_inhibition_of_sperm_under_guidance#Advantages) does mention reversal being repeatedly succesful in primates. No citations, though... Further, your comment seems weirdly aggressive *("...absolutely no credible..."),* considering there's *also* no claims that it *woudn't* be reversible.

Comment: They say the gel rips the sperm in half using a polarizing effect. I just don't get why/how your sperm can be polar enough to react and be torn by such a small force. If this effect is true then I should be able to put sperm in between two magnets and have all of them die in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Louis: I'm scratching my head, trying to remember my high-school physics. Are you confusing electrical and magnetic polarity?

Comment: @oddthinking - in this context the two should be equivalent.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I forget more than I remember, so this is a query not a claim: H2O has polarity. Being able to break apart water with a strong magnet doesn't sound right. Why is that different (if indeed it is)?

Comment: Ahhh - I understand what you mean now. It is the difference between a magnetic field, and an electric current that differentiates these. Incidentally - you can use a magnet, it just needs to be hoofingly powerful:-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You seem to have two main questions here, asking if RISUG exists and if so, if it is safe and effective. I will answer each in turn.

**Does RISUG exist?**

There is little question that RISUG exists, as there is an abundance of evidence.

- There is a patent filed in the US which shows at the least that the design/technique exists<sup>[(1)](http://www.google.com/patents?vid=5488075)</sup>.
- There are several peer reviewed studies introducing and exploring RISUG<sup>[(2)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7056760), [(3)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15722073)</sup>.
- RISIG has been reported in numerous credible media sources such as Forbes<sup>[(4)](http://www.forbes.com/sites/daviddisalvo/2012/05/11/are-men-ready-for-an-injection-of-contraception/)</sup> and Wired<sup>[(5)](http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/04/ff_vasectomy/all/1)</sup>. If RISUG did not exist it seems likely that it would have been exposed by now with a retraction printed.
- There are clinical trials currently underway in India<sup>[(6)](http://www.webcitation.org/5zHEacvXH)</sup>.
- It is currently undergoing FDA trials in the USA under the name Vasalgel<sup>[(7)](http://www.parsemusfoundation.org/Parsemus/New_male_contraceptives.html)</sup>.

**Is RISUG safe?**

There have been a lot of studies done so far based on a number of clinical trials on humans and animals. While the results may not be conclusive, it certainly seems that RISUG is as safe and effective as claimed.

A 2001 study<sup>[(8)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11597307)</sup> found that  “the intervention of RISUG in the vas deferens even for a period as long as 8 years is absolutely safe and does not lead to prostatic diseases.”

A 2005 study found that<sup>[(9)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15897977)</sup> “SMA vas occlusion and its non-invasive reversal do not damage the accessory reproductive organs.”

The results of a 2003 study<sup>[(10)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12826690)</sup> on langur monkeys found that RISUG does not cause sperm granulomas to form (a reaction of sperm leaking into surrounding tissue) which can be painful for some men.

The results of a 1999 study<sup>[(11)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10361629)</sup>  indicated that the vas deferens returns to normal after the removal of RISUG. These results toger indicate that RISUG has less of a health impact than a vasectomy does.

As far as reversing the procedure, a 2005 study again using langur monkeys as test subjects found reversal was safe without adverse side effects.<sup>[(3)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15722073)</sup>

All the studies so far show no adverse reactions or side effects and far less of an impact on the reproductive organs than existing methods.

In addition to all of that there is also the possibility that RISUG could prevent the transmission of HIV to partners, which certainly would do a lot for health in general<sup>[(12)](http://www.medical-hypotheses.com/article/S0306-9877%2805%2900096-4/abstract)</sup>.

**Is RISUG effective?**

As far as effectiveness goes, it seems that RISUG takes effect almost immediately and is successful in inducing azoospermia.

A Phase 2 clinical trial conducted over 12 months found that all test subjects had azoospermia . No pregnancies were reported and the method was considered safe<sup>[(13)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9408706)</sup>.

A second follow up study from 1998<sup>[(14)](http://www.contraceptionjournal.org/article/S0010-7824%2898%2900096-1/abstract)</sup> had similar results to the 1997 study, except this time the method was shown to be effective for a two year period.

Finally, in a third study from 2003<sup>[(15)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12521662)</sup>  performed on a group of 25 men, six of the men developed azoospermia within the first month, an additional 15 in the second month, with the last 4 men following in the third and fourth months. No pregancies were reported over a six month period.

**All signs point to yes**

All the evidence we have so far indicates that RISUG is indeed safe and effective. It looks like it should be appearing for use by consumers in the next few years in the USA if the FDA trials go well.

---

<sub>(1): http://www.google.com/patents?vid=5488075</sub>

<sub>(2): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7056760</sub>

<sub>(3): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15722073</sub>

<sub>(4): http://www.forbes.com/sites/daviddisalvo/2012/05/11/are-men-ready-for-an-injection-of-contraception/</sub>

<sub>(5): http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/04/ff_vasectomy/all/1</sub>

<sub>(6): http://www.webcitation.org/5zHEacvXH</sub>

<sub>(7): http://www.parsemusfoundation.org/Parsemus/New_male_contraceptives.html</sub>

<sub>(8): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11597307</sub>

<sub>(9): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15897977</sub>

<sub>(10): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12826690</sub>

<sub>(11): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10361629</sub>

<sub>(12): http://www.medical-hypotheses.com/article/S0306-9877(05)00096-4/abstract</sub>

<sub>(13): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9408706</sub>

<sub>(14): http://www.contraceptionjournal.org/article/S0010-7824%2898%2900096-1/abstract</sub>

<sub>(15): http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12521662</sub>

Comment: ... I probably just don't understand how azoospermia works, but how come the method can be said to "take effect almost immediately" if in the 2003 study only 6/25 had azoospermia in 1 month, and total 21/25 in 2 months? That doesn't seem very immediate to me.